# Update dropdown options, but keep selected

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list of companies.  I also have some dropdown lists of contacts (primary_contact, sales_contact, insurance_contact) which all belong to class "contact".  When the company changes, I update the list of available contacts using the following code:

```
$('#company').change(function () {
        var company = $(this)[0].value.toString();
        $.getJSON('<%= ResolveUrl("~/Subcontracts/CompanyContacts/") %>' + company, null, function (data) {
            $('.contact').empty().append("<option value=''>**Select Contact**</option>");
            $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                $('.contact').append("<option value='" + optionData.contact_id + "'>" + optionData.contact_name + "</option>");

            });
        });
    });
```

Some contacts are valid for multiple subsidiaries.  If the previously selected contact shows up in the new contact list, I would like for them to still be selected.  So, if the previously selected sales_contact is in the list, select them. Same for primary_contact and insurance_contact. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if this is the "best" way, but I got it to work by doing this:

```
 $('#company').change(function () {
            var company = $(this)[0].value.toString();
            var primary_contact = $('#primary_contact').val();
            var safety_contact = $('#safety_contact').val();
            var insurance_contact = $('#insurance_contact').val();
            $.getJSON('<%= ResolveUrl("~/Subcontracts/CompanyContacts/") %>' + company, null, function (data) {
                $('.contact').empty().append("<option value=''>**Select Contact**</option>");
                $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                    $('.contact').append("<option value='" + optionData.contact_id + "'>" + optionData.contact_name + "</option>");
                });
                $('#primary_contact').val(primary_contact);
                $('#safety_contact').val(safety_contact);
                $('#insurance_contact').val(insurance_contact);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$('#company').change(function () {
    var company = $(this)[0].value.toString();

    for (var i=0; i<this.options.length; i++){
        if (this.options[i].selected==true){
            var contact = this.options[i].value.toString();
            break;
        }
    }



        $.getJSON('<%= ResolveUrl("~/Subcontracts/CompanyContacts/") %>' + company, null, function (data) {
            $('.contact').empty().append("<option value=''>**Select Contact**</option>");
            $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
        if (optionData.contact_id == contact)
                   $('.contact').append("<option value='" + optionData.contact_id + " selected='selected''>" + optionData.contact_name + "</option>");
        else 
                 $('.contact').append("<option value='" + optionData.contact_id + "'>" + optionData.contact_name + "</option>");
            });
        });
    });
```